# How to combine multiple call to Ajax Data base from different JS files

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some code on a file that makes Ajax calls. This file is being called as a function by multiple other files that creates a new instance each time.

This is the JS code that is being called:

```js
define(["underscore", "homeop", "domReady!"],
    function (_, homeop, domready) {
         
        var timeout = 500;
        return function (opUrl, opList, onCallback) {

            // IRRELEVANT CODE 
          
          var getFetch = function (optionName) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: optionsUrl,
                        data: { optionNames: [optionName] }, 
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false,
                        traditional: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            _.each(data, function (optionData, optionName) {
                                if (homeop.globalCache[optionName] === null) {
                                    homeop.globalCache[optionName] = optionData;
                                }
                            });
                            
                        },
                        error: function (message) {
                            console.error(message.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                };
          
          self.getInfo = function (optionName) {
            if (homeop.globalCache[optionName] === undefined) {
                    if (!_.contains(homeop.getOption(), optionName)) {
                        getFetch(optionName);
                    }
              
              // MORE IRRELEVANT CODE GOES HERE
```

In other JS files, I call the get function; for example

```js
var these = new getOptions(optionsUrl, optionsList, onLoadCallback);
var getOpt = these.get(OptionsUrl);
```

The problem is I am making multiple calls to the get information from the database causing multiple call to my JS file. Each new instance of the JS file will create a ajax call.

Is there a way to wait for all the calls to be done and then get data from the database? In other words how can I somehow combine all the call to my 'getOption.js'?

Thanks

Comment: This could be solved by using JS Promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. You can also implement queue in place of stack

```js
var optionStack = [];
var isAvailable = true;
var getFetch = function (optionName) {
  if(isAvailable){
      isAvilable = false; // function not available now
  }
  else {
    optionStack.push(optionName)
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: optionsUrl,
    data: { optionNames: [optionName] }, 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
      _.each(data, function (optionData, optionName) {
        if (homeop.globalCache[optionName] === null) {
          homeop.globalCache[optionName] = optionData;
        }
      });

    },
    error: function (message) {
      console.error(message.responseText);
    },
    done: function (){
      isAvailable = true;
      if(optionStack.length > 0){
        getFetch(optionStack.pop());
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! the 'isAvailable' flag and the 'done' function helped!

Comment: At first it thought it helped, but it did not really. Thanks anyway!